# regarding suppressing the warning message

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

While running a python project, I got the following warning message,

```
numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:3417: FutureWarning: In a future version, DataFrame.mean(axis=None) will return a scalar mean over the entire DataFrame. To retain the old behavior, use 'frame.mean(axis=0)' or just 'frame.mean()'
```

Are there any ways to suppress this kind of warning message, and will it cause any hidden risk?

Answer (score 0):

I also has the warning while I calculate root mean square error

```
def rmse(y_true, y_pred):
    return np.sqrt(np.mean((y_true - y_pred)**2))
```

And, after I add `axis=0`, the warning message disappear

```
def rmse(y_true, y_pred):
    return np.sqrt(np.mean((y_true - y_pred)**2, axis=0))
```

I think that warning is from my DataFrame object, which has many rows with only one column.